# Get a list of the charges on a Stripe account connected via Stripe Connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

How do you get a list of customer charges on a connected Stripe account?

For the main account, I use this:

```
  Stripe::Charge.all(customer: stripe_id).data
```

But I can't find any documentation on getting charges off of another account without changing the `Stripe.api_key` for that call alone, which seems like a terrible practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to add the `stripe_account` key to the options hash of the Stripe API call:

```
  Stripe::Charge.all(
    { customer: stripe_id },
    stripe_account: connected_account_id
  ).data
```

Comment: `connected_account_id` - Where can I get it?

Comment: that is the ID of the Connect account that your Platform is connected to. Looks like `acct_12345`