# List all charges of a Connected Stripe Account

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have stripe platform with connected stripe accounts.

I would like to obtain all charges that have been made on a particular connected account.

User connected account id:

> acct_xxx

The only documentation I can find is for retrieved customers based on secret api keys.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_xxx');

const charges = await stripe.charges.list({
  limit: 3,
});
```

I need to obtain all charges of a connected account. Not charges on the platforms customers.

I found a similar stack overflow question for ruby. [Get a list of the charges on a Stripe account connected via Stripe Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411609/get-a-list-of-the-charges-on-a-stripe-account-connected-via-stripe-connect)

I do not know how to achieve this using node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the Stripe-Account header to make API calls "on Connect accounts": https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header

Most of Stripe's client libraries (like stripe-node) allow passing a parameter with each API call function, in the options hash, like:

```
const charges = await stripe.charges.list(
  {
    limit: 3,
  },
  {
    stripeAccount: 'acct_12345'
  }
);
```